# Word to describe a person who doesn't come here for the first time (or negative of first-timer)?

Tags: single-word-requests

Suppose I am handing invitations to an event that occurs with a certain regularity. A person that is attending for the first-time can be called a "first-timer". What's the negative of that expression? What word can I use to refer to a person that has come to at least one previous occurrence of the event?

Comment: A regular: [use 25](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/regular?s=t)

Comment: @VampDuc "regular" seems to imply that this person comes regularly. However, I just want to convey that this person has come at least once before.

Comment: A "repeat visitor", perhaps.

Comment: @Hellion Something like that. But perhaps there is something more idiomatic?

Comment: idiomatically we say, "All of you ***who have been here before***" raise your hand.

Comment: maybe a ***past attendee***?

Comment: The antonym for a person who visits a place for the first time is someone who habitually visits that place and, in fact, has visited it countless times—and I think _regular_ conveys that sense quite well. A word for someone who has visited a place at least once before is not by any stretch an antonym for someone who is visiting for the first time—that's like saying that _sophomore_ is the antonym of _freshman_ because one has been in college for at least one year and the other has not been in college for at least one year. As formulated, your question is rather confusing.

Comment: @SvenYargs I meant antonym in the sense of logical negation (I am not a linguist so correct me if this is a wrong usage of 'antonym'). If you negate the statement "John Doe is visiting for the first time" you obtain "John Doe has visited at least once before". Do you agree?

Comment: "John Doe has visited at least once before" is indeed a logical negation of "John Doe is visiting for the first time," as is "John Doe is not visiting and never has visited." But in my view neither alternative wording is the opposite (antonym) of "John Doe is visiting for the first time," A person who has $999,999.99 falls into the category of nonmillionaires (people who are, as a class, the negative of millionaires), but it would be odd to argue that he or she is therefore the opposite of a millionaire. I think your question would be clearer if you got rid of the term _antonym_ altogether.

Comment: @SvenYargs Replaced *antonym* with *opposite*. Better?

Comment: I appreciate your effort and have upvoted your question on that basis. But I really think that if the point of your question is to find a word that refers to the negative of _first-timer_, you're better of with "(or negative of 'first-timer')" than with either "(or antonym of 'first-timer')" or "(or opposite of 'first-timer')." However, I begin to think that I've bugged you enough with my ratiocinations on this point.

Answer (score 1):

If you get together to do something,

**old hand**

> noun
>   a person with a lot of experience in something.
>   "he was an old hand at red-tape cutting"

-Google

As in, "We play poker every week.  There are two or three novices each session, and the rest are old hands like me."

If you're just meeting somewhere:

**Regular**

> noun
>   1. a regular customer or member, for example of a bar, store, or team.
>   "attracting a richer clientele as its regulars"

-Google

Comment: about "regular", see http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/269826/word-to-describe-a-person-who-doesnt-come-here-for-the-first-time-or-antonym-o#comment594978_269826.

Answer (score 1):

> **alumnus** plural *alum·ni*-ˌnī\
>
> :  a person who has attended or has graduated from a particular
>   school, college, or university
>
> :  a person who is a former member, employee, contributor, or inmate

(Courtesy of Merriam-Webster)

Comment: Hmmm, *alum* is a nice one.

Answer (score 1):

***experienced attendees***

[A real world example](http://cochlearimplantonline.com/site/getting-the-most-out-of-your-agbell2014-convention-experience/) :

> AG Bell Convention 2014 is just two weeks away.  The countdown has begun!  As you begin to pack your suitcases, here are a few tips for how to get the most out of your Convention experience for *first-timers and experienced attendees* alike.

[and another one](http://www.acog.org/About_ACOG/ACOG_Departments/District_Newsletters/District_VIII/May_2013/Section_reports?p=1) :

> Enthusiasm from section members has forced us to limit the number of interested candidates who participate in the CLC as we strive to bring a wide geographic distribution and a mix of *first-timers and experienced attendees*.